# Validar dato anterior con el dato nuevo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Les planteo la situación, tengo una serie de registros que puedo editar y tengo un campo de porcentaje, entonces lo que deseo es que al momento de editar me valide que no pueda ingresar un porcentaje menor al anterior, osea edito y en el la caja de texto me aparece 20 y si le pongo 10 no me deje ya que es menor.

Comment: Usa el evento que se dispara al cambiar el valor (o al enviar solicitud). Crea una variable donde guardes el valor del registro. Dentro del evento primero verifica que el valor nuevo sea mayor que el valor que guarda la variable, en caso de ser verdadero guarda en la variable el nuevo valor. Inicializa la variable con el valor más mínimo

Comment: Has de añadir el codigo que tengas, de tus campos. No podemos trabajar sobre el aire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funcionalidad que entendí la muestro en el siguiente ejemplo, espero te pueda servir, saludos.

Mira este ejemplo con `jquery`:

```js
var valorAnterior;
$(document).ready(function() {
  valorAnterior = 0;
  $("#porcentaje").change(function() {
    $(".error").css("display", "none");
    var valorNuevo = parseFloat($(this).val());
    valorNuevo = isNaN(valorNuevo) ? 0 : valorNuevo;
    if (valorAnterior == 0) {
      valorAnterior = valorNuevo;
    } else {
      if (valorNuevo < valorAnterior) {
        $(".error").text("El valor no puede ser Menor que " + valorAnterior);
        $(".error").css("display", "block");
        $("#porcentaje").val(0);

      } else {
        valorAnterior = valorNuevo;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Porcentaje
<input id="porcentaje" />
<div class="error" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: Siento que te amo. Gracias muchas gracias

Comment: Que lindo :-)  @JesusGaleano. Cualquier duda que tengas con mucho gusto te apoyo.  Saludos desde Sinaloa.